# Not a sudoku, but still fun?

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, story, grid-deduction, reverse-puzzling

Context:
I was trying to solve some of the puzzles on this site, when it occurred to me to make a puzzle variant myself.
I immediately could construct one with my additional rule. Making an interesting one was harder, but I succeeded.
I was unsure whether this was actually fun to solve so I gave it to my test panel first. However, I know little more than the internet names of my contestants.

What I want you to figure out:

What are the real names of my top contestants?
What kind of game did I make?
Can you make such a puzzle for 10; can you for 11? 1 answer here is enough, bonus points for both answers.

Some information about my test panel:
Gold went to Anna. She is a real thinker, so it should not be a surprise that number 1 is all she is.
Victor ended second place. He is number two all the time. Well, except once, but that is beside the point.
Number 3 calls himself Ivan. He is unrelated to Anna and Victor. He is really into sudokus. He is a bit random but always ends up in the top 10.

Tactical tip from Anna:
Divide and conquer, that is what I use.
Victor is a scrawny fanatic vegetarian; Ivan likes his meat and has a lot of meat on his body to show for it. Obviously that shows in what they stand for; I use that to make sure they do not cooperate against me.

[image]

Time for some hints to get started:

> Look at Anna.

> Did you notice the mathematics tag?

Note: This first multilayered puzzle of mine does not seem to attract answers or many votes. Maybe I am just impatient, but any partial answers will be appreciated, even if only for me to figure out what is blocking.

Some additional hints:

> 'Anna' is quite famous. Even if you don't know mathematics, you could easily look her up. Then find out why she seems to win all the time.

> 'Ivan' is even more famous, however you will need Anna to find him.

> 'Victor' is not famous at all. I now think this is a weakness in this puzzle, he is almost useless like this. I should have then given him a last name, if only to honor some people. Victor Bubbler, or better Victor Euler, but then I should have let him be number 1 most of the time.

New hint:

> 'Victor' is the square root of 2. The vegetarian <-> root link was a vague hint that this was correct. -Not that I expected this to be found before Anna was identified-

Comment: This seems as if it might want the [reverse-puzzling] tag. (On the face of it it certainly does, but in an [enigmatic-puzzle] all may not be as it seems.)

Comment: I think you are right, done. Still, following the clues is a bigger part than doing something with the emerging puzzle, so I'm not so sure. If it is solved, I'll appreciate an opinion about the labels.

Comment: You may very well not want to answer this, but just in case it's meant to be more obvious than (to me) it is: Is the "sudoku" in the image intended to be an instance of the same type of puzzle as the one we're being challenged to identify?

Comment: No, the puzzle will emerge if the hints are understood/applied correctly